# Sorting by distance with a related ManyToMany field

Tags: django, geodjango, django-orm

I have this two models.

```
class Store(models.Model):
    coords = models.PointField(null=True,blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

class Product(models.Model):
    stores  = models.ManyToManyField(Store, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

I want to get the products sorted by the distance to a point. If the stores field in Product was a Foreign Key I would do this and it works.

```
pnt = GEOSGeometry('POINT(5 23)')
Product.objects.distance(pnt, field_name='stores__coords').order_by('distance')
```

But since the field is a ManyToMany field it breaks with

```
ValueError: <django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields.PointField: coords> is not in list
```

I kind of expected this because it's not clear which of the stores it should use to calculate the distance, but is there any way to do this.

I need the list of products ordered by distance to a specific point.

Comment: I've been having this difficulty also.  Maybe this isn't possible with GeoDjango?  Perhaps one must create a raw sql for it?

Comment: @JoeJ I'll post what I did as a possible answer but I dont like it. Probably the raw SQL can work but I'm not very confortable with spatial queries and that. Check out the answer and see what you think.

Comment: Product has a `ManyToMany` to `Store`, but it is the store who has the `PointField`. A product can be in 1 or more stores... **Wich is the distance for a Product that has more than 1 store ?** The lower ? The higher ? All ?

Comment: @Liarez Great question. In my case it was the closest one. I needed a product search showing products around you on a map.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, maybe this would work for you, this should take only two database queries (due to how prefetch works). Don't judge harshly if it doesn't work, I haven't tried it:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    coords = models.PointField(null=True,blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

class Product(models.Model):
    stores  = models.ManyToManyField(Store, null=True, blank=True, through='ProductStore')
    objects = models.GeoManager()

class ProductStore(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

then:

```
pnt = GEOSGeometry('POINT(5 23)')
ps = ProductStore.objects.distance(pnt, field_name='store__coords').order_by('distance').prefetch_related('product')
for p in ps:
    p.product ... # do whatever you need with it
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I posted this over a year ago and unfortunately I don't have access to the code or a way to test this anymore. If someone finds that it works for them I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it but I dont really like this solution. I think is very inefficient. There should be a better way with GeoDjango. So, until i find a better solution I probably wont be using this. Here's what I did.

I added a new method to the product model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    stores  = models.ManyToManyField(Store, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def get_closes_store_distance(point):
        sorted_stores =  self.stores.distance(point).order_by('distance')
        if sorted_stores.count() > 0:
            store = sorted_stores[0]
            return store.distance.m
        return 99999999 # If no store, return very high distance
```

Then I can sort this way

```
def sort_products(self, obj_list, lat, lng):
    pt = 'POINT(%s %s)' % (lng, lat)
    srtd = sorted(obj_list, key=lambda obj: obj.get_closest_store_distance(pt))
    return srtd
```

Any better solutions or ways to improve this one are very welcome.

Comment: Did you happen to find an efficient solution?

Comment: @VikasGulati & manuel: I will repeat a comment to the question (that VikasGulati may not have seen): What is "distance from a product to a point"? (Probably the minimum distance from the point to a store with that product.) What is the output exactly? (Probably a list of (product, distance) for all products sorted by distance ascending.)

Comment: @philipxy: Yes distance is the minimum one. And output that I was looking to achieve in a similar problem was List of Products sorted by the calculated minimum distance + Each product should have the related stores pre-fetched sorted by distance again.

Answer (score 0):

I will take "distance from a product to a point" to be the minimum distance from the point to a store with that product. I will take the output to be a list of (product, distance) for all products sorted by distance ascending. (A comment by someone who placed a bounty indicated they sometimes also want (product,distance,store) sorted by distance then store within product.)

Every model has a corresponding table. The fields of the model are the columns of the table. Every model/table should have a fill-in-the-(named-)blanks statement where its records/rows are the ones that make a true statement.

```
Store(coords,...) // store [store] is at [coords] and ...
Product(product,store,...) // product [product] is stocked by store [store] and ...
```

Since Product has store(s) as manyToManyField it already is a "ProductStore" table of products and stocking stores and Store already is a "StoreCoord" table of stores and their coordinates.

You can mention any object's fields in a query filter() for a model with a manyToManyField.

The SQL for this is simple:

```
select p.product,distance
    select p.product,distance(s.coord,[pnt]) as distance
    from Store s join Product p
    on s.store=p.store
group by product
having distance=min(distance)
order by distance
```

It should be straightforward to map this to a [query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/). However, I am not familiar enough with Django to give you exact code now.

```
from django.db.models import F

q = Product.objects.all()
    .filter(store__product=F('product'))
    ...
    .annotate(distance=Min('coord.distance([pnt])'))
    ...
    .order_by('distance')
```

The Min() is an example of [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/).

You may also be helped by explicitly making a [subquery](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/236/).

It is also possible to query this by the [raw](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/sql/) interface. However, the names above are not right for a Django raw query. Eg the table names will by default be APPL_store and APPL_product where APPL is your application name. Also, distance is not your pointField operator. You must give the right distance function. But you should not need to query at the raw level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I posted this over a year ago and unfortunately I don't have access to the code or a way to test this anymore. If someone finds that it works for them I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Understand. (A bounty was posted on it recently by [Vikas Gulati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1283546/vikas-gulati).)